# How to execute a PHP function which is stored in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am looking to execute a php function which is stored in mysql table.
e.g

```
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `modules` WHERE uid=2 LIMIT 0, 30 ;

Rows: 1

uid     moduleName  source  responsiveCode  active  
2   Testimonial     this is a function <?php echo getUrl(); ?>  12  0
```

now i want to execute getUrl() function whenever i retrive the uid  number 2

Comment: You can look into http://php.net/eval but take notice that this can be a huge security issue.

Comment: As pointed out, this is a *very bad practice*. If there s a way of not evaluating functions stored in DB, please think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `eval()` like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `modules` WHERE uid=2 LIMIT 0, 30");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$function = $row['source'];

eval('?>' . $function . '<?php');
```

I strongly disadvise you to store your functions in a database though, since it brings in a huge security risk. Instead, you could do it like this:

```
uid | moduleName  | source             | responsiveCode | active 
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
2   | Testimonial | this is a function | 12             | 0

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `modules` WHERE uid=2 LIMIT 0, 30");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['source'] . getUrl(); //will still print the same
```

Comment: If eval is disabled (and it often is), you could write the function to the file and than include it -- _could_ doesn't mean that it's a good idea

Comment: @Paladin good idea. But it would take longer than simply `eval()`, especially if the functions are long

Comment: Also keep in mind multiple reads to the same file would produce unexpected results. Neither `eval` or `include` are recommended to accomplish what the OP is wanting to achieve as they represents serious security risks.

Comment: @Jonan Yeah, it would be slower.. but it only option how to handle enviroment without eval.. but I really don't thing there would be correlation between lenght of the function and processing time. The I/O would be slow but after that I don't see it depending on the lenght of the function too much.. @ fyrye of course, there would have to be some protection against that

Comment: @fyrye true, but I don't see any way of automatically checking if a function poses a secirity threat or not (although I suppose you could isolate the function in some way so it can't reach any variables). @ Paladin I don't really know for sure if a longer function will take longer, but it just seems logical to me that writing 3 lines to a file is faster than hundreds of them... Also: why is there sudden activity on this 3 months old question? :P

Comment: Better solution would be to save the $row['source'] data to a physical unique filename as opposed to in the database. Then use $row['source'] to store the unique filename. When retrieving the row value, call `include $row['source'];` Lower database data size, and rely on IO for the include. As for the security risks, it appears that the OP is trying to implement a CMS that executes PHP code which is never advisable. As for the thread activity your answer pushed it to the top of the list.

Comment: @fyrye Good idea. But how did `Paladin` get to this post?

Comment: It looks like @Tshepang edited the original post which pushed it back to the top of the list.